# React Native get correct status bar height on android

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to get the status bar height on Android devices using React Native's StatusBar.currentHeight https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/statusbar. On a pixel 2, that variable is 24 when in fact the status bar height is 19. Does anyone know of a way to get the correct status bar height on all devices with React Native?

Comment: In my case, `StatusBar.currentHeight` is 49.09090805053711 while it actually is 62, on a Pixel 4 emulator.

How did you solve this eventually?

Comment: @Scottw any news on this? Have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 7):

You can try download the `expo-constants` module.

```js
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
...
const STATUSBAR_HEIGHT = Constants.statusBarHeight
```

> EDIT

OR

you can use `react-native-safe-area-context`

- sample

```
import { useSafeAreaInsets } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

function HookComponent() {
  const insets = useSafeAreaInsets();

  useEffect(() => {
     const { top , bottom , left , right } = insets // typeof { top: number, right: number, bottom: number, left: number }
     console.log(top , bottom , left , right)
  },[insets])

  return <View style={{ paddingBottom: Math.max(insets.bottom, 16) }} />;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Dimensions, StatusBar } from 'react-native'

const { height: SCREEN_HEIGHT, width: SCREEN_WIDTH } = Dimensions.get('window');
const STATUSBAR_HEIGHT = StatusBar.currentHeight;
```

Comment: StatusBar.currentHeight seems to report the wrong information on some devices. As said it the question on the pixel 2 you will get back 24 when the height is actually 19